# How to make NestedScrollingParent continue fling after NestedScrollingChilding fling stopped

Tags: android, nestedscrollview

I have two views, one is RecyclerView, the other one is customer defined NestedScrollingParent. The RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollingParent view. My question is how to continue the fling in NestedScrollingParent after RecyclerView fling stopped(The RecyclerView reached the top edge).

Comment: Any code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution? I met the same issue